# Cocoa (Mac): splitting / combining a core data based application from / into multiple save files

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nspersistentdocument

I'm working in OS X Lion on a Core Data based Cocoa application where I need to be able to save different parts, lets say partA and partB, of the data model into separate files.

I need to be able to save both files together as a project file/package, but also need to be able to load and save partA independently from partB.

Loading a new partA file should replace all data currently associated with partA.
Saving partA should not save data changed in partB.

Entities in partA do need to maintain relationships with entities in partB but these can (and most likely have to) be weak.

My main question is: What would be the best approach for implementing the desired features?

---

My first approach has been one `NSManagedObjectModel` containing two configurations, one for each of the parts. I have two `NSPersistentStore` instances assigned to my `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` one for each of the configurations. And one `NSManagedObjectContext` instance with the `storeCoordinator` assigned to it.

Saving and opening separate files are currently my main concerns in this appraoch. `NSManagedObjectContext` `-save:` message seems to save both configurations. Is it possible to only save changes made to objects that belong to a specific configuration of the `NSManagedObjectModel`? Or would I need two `NSManagedObjectContext` instances, one for each of the configurations?

Opening a file by adding a store to the `persistentStoreCoordinator` for partA adds data to the context and so far I have not been able to replace data. Is there a way to know which store is associated with a certain configuration, perhaps by sending a message to the `persistentStoreCoordinator`?

I'm also thinking of a second approach: Setting up two subclasses of `NSPersistentDocument` one for each configuration in my data model to be able to save the data into separate files. But I'm not sure if having two separate `NSManagedObjectContext` instances would allow setting up relationships between `NSManagedObject` subclasses in the different configurations?

If anyone has a good idea or can point me in the right direction or even has an example of how I could implement the above features, that would be highly appreciated.